# how to use most recent dev version of a package in julia?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to dev a julia package. I have it in `~/.julia/dev/<PackageName>`, and I'm testing the modifications that I make to it in another REPL, using `Pkg.develop()` and `Pkg.free()` to switch to and from the development version of the package.
The problem is that I don't seem to be able use the most recent changes (not commited) I made to the package by using `Pkg.develop()`. What am I doing wrong? is there a way to avoid commiting the package changes before testing them? What is a good workflow for deving and testing packages?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

`Pkg.develop` should not care about the commit, or even about the folder being a git repo, and should just look at the current state of the files on the disk. So when you locally update files in your developed package, the next time you load the package (in the environment where it is added using `Pkg.develop`) you should see the changes you made. This can also be made more convenient using `Revise.jl` so you don't have to restart Julia each time you make updates.

So let's say you have a package, call it `PkgA`, in `~/.julia/dev/PkgA`. You have a REPL open with some environment active where you have run `Pkg.develop("PkgA")`.

After making some changes in PkgA, you would then:

- Without Revise - restart the REPL, activating the same environment, run `using PkgA` again, and now you should have the most recent changes.
- With Revise - Make sure to run `using Revise` before you run `using PkgA`, and then Revise will detect any changes in `~/.julia/dev/PkgA` and reload them in the running session. As soon as you save they should be available in the REPL.